# Deny loading of a 3rd party framework in iOS 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker

Is it possible to deny loading of a statically packaged framework in iOS, conditionally at run time?

I've got a 3rd party framework in my app and it works okay on iOS 6 and iOS 7, but it crashes on load on iOS 5. The framework in question uses `NSLayoutConstraint` and `dyld` crashes the app on start, saying symbol not found.

Ideally I'd like to disable the framework from loading and show users a `UIAlertView` saying this functionality is only available in iOS6+ when they try to access it, but I can't figure out how to *not* load the 3rd party framework.

The 3rd party framework is not under my control; I cannot alter it.

I tried linking it optionally and using NSClassFromString, if I remove all direct references to the framework then it doesn't get linked into my app at all. Further from this, if I force inclusion using -force in linker flags then the app still crashes on iOS 5.

I'd appreciate any other ideas as well; I'm at the end of my wits about this. :(

Comment: Drop support for iOS5... .framework, not .bundle, yes?

Comment: Yeah, it's a framework, not a bundle. I wish I could have dropped iOS 5 support, that is not an option for me. :(

Comment: I guess you'll need to build a bundle to contain the framework and then optionally load that bundle at runtime...

Comment: It is not allowed and possible to load dynamic frameworks on iOS until (including) iOS 7. Only iOS 8 introduces dynamic frameworks. A bundle does not help in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** possible. Since libraries are statically linked, there is nothing you can not load on runtime. Dynamic frameworks on iOS will be introduced with iOS 8.

The only options you have are:

1. Don't use that 3rd party framework at all.
2. Modify it (if you have to source) and remove AutoLayout usage.
3. Drop iOS 5 support in your app.